# How do I only get the error stream when using call in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

In the following example, I can get both the error stream and the output stream to a variable when using the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6#special-operators). `$command` is an external program.

```
$output = & $command $args 2>&1
```

The [redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-6) does not provide any information to help.

However, I want *only* the error output. How can I do this?